# SQL Server Database auditing not working

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

I'm [setting up auditing on a SQL Server Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-auditing) in Azure (Version = `Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8`).  Following the instructions in the link, everything worked for server-level auditing.  I created a container called `sql-audit-logs` and then proceeded to set up everything:

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL [https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/sql-audit-logs]
WITH IDENTITY='SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'sas-token'
GO

USE master
GO

CREATE SERVER AUDIT [myserveraudit]
TO URL ( PATH ='https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/sql-audit-logs', RETENTION_DAYS = 0)
GO


CREATE SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION [myserverauditspec]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [myserveraudit]  
    ADD(APPLICATION_ROLE_CHANGE_PASSWORD_GROUP)
    ,ADD(AUDIT_CHANGE_GROUP)
    ,... <excluded for brevity>
WITH ( STATE = ON);
GO
```

And using Azure Storage Explorer, I started getting log data almost immediately:

[image]

I then set up database-level auditing for one of my databases:

```
USE MyDB
GO

CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [mydatabaseauditspec]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [myserveraudit]  
    ADD(APPLICATION_ROLE_CHANGE_PASSWORD_GROUP)
    ,ADD(DBCC_GROUP)
    ,ADD(DATABASE_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP)
    ,...<excluded for brevity>
WITH ( STATE = ON);
GO
```

But I'm not seeing any logs being created.  With the `DBCC_GROUP` setting I should get a log any time someone runs a DBCC on `MyDB` but despite executing a DBCC, nothing is logged.  I've also tried creating and dropping tables (should be logged because of `DATABASE_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP`) but nothing.

I've checked the tables:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.database_audit_specifications
SELECT * FROM sys.database_audit_specification_details
```

And I can see that the specifications I defined in my T-SQL were created and the `is_state_enable` is 1.  But still no logs.

Am I missing a step somewhere?  I tried turning the server audit off and then on again but that didn't have any effect.

Comment: I know it lets you to create the database audit specification but look at the [books online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-audit-specification-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), it appears `database audit specification` is not supported for Manged Instance.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide Thanks for the response.  Sounds possible (no support for database audit), but the [books online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-server-audit-specification-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for a `server audit` don't indicate support for managed instance but it appears to be working.  Could be just "luck"...